# Why I am getting such a message:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method fetchProvidersForEmail(Ljava/lang/String;)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create an Android program, and met an error of which I have no idea how to solve.
My app crashes after I put in the email. I suspect that the problem is related with firebase. I have tried different ways of solving of this problem, such as changing the versions of firebase implementations, but without any success.

Here is my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.chat.mychatapp;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.github.library.bubbleview.BubbleTextView;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import android.text.format.DateFormat;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static int SIGN_IN_CODE = 1;
    private RelativeLayout activity_main;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<Message> adapter;
    private FloatingActionButton sendBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Snackbar.make(activity_main, "You are authorized", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                displayAllMessages();
            }else{
                Snackbar.make(activity_main, "You are NOT authorized", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        activity_main = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText textField = findViewById(R.id.messageField);
                if(textField.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    return;
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue(
                    new Message(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getEmail(),
                            textField.getText().toString()
                    )
                );
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });
        //User not autorized
        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null){
            startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(), SIGN_IN_CODE);
        }else{
            Snackbar.make(activity_main, "You are authorized", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            displayAllMessages();
        }

    }

    private void displayAllMessages() {
        ListView listOfMessages = findViewById(R.id.messageList);
        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Message>(this, Message.class, R.layout.list_item, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Message model, int position) {
                TextView m_user, m_time;
                BubbleTextView m_text;
                m_user = v.findViewById(R.id.messageUser);
                m_time = v.findViewById(R.id.messageTime);
                m_text = v.findViewById(R.id.messageText);

                m_user.setText(model.getUserName());
                m_text.setText(model.getMessage());
                m_time.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-mm-yyyy  HH:mm:ss",model.getTime()));

            }
        };
        listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chat.mychatapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
    implementation 'com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.chat.mychatapp, PID: 18455
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method fetchProvidersForEmail(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth' appears in /data/app/com.chat.mychatapp-s_3u6mmiv0A6KE9ijznfqQ==/base.apk)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.AcquireEmailHelper.checkAccountExists(AcquireEmailHelper.java:55)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.SignInNoPasswordActivity.onClick(SignInNoPasswordActivity.java:73)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7339)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14222)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7305)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27787)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

Comment: Did u try the answer

Answer (score 1):

Update the following dependency:

```
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
```

into this:

```
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:6.2.0'
```

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#auth_v17-0-0):

> Removed the deprecated `fetchProvidersForEmail(String)` method from the FirebaseAuth class, as well as the associated ProviderQueryResult class. Use `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(String)` instead.

Therefore update the `firebaseUI` and you can use `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(String)` instead.